# Reporting Services 2022 command line installation does not support creating an instance or database?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2022

My company's software comes bundled with (at the moment) SQL Server Express 2014 with Reporting Services. We want to upgrade to 2022 Express and are running into a few hurdles. The old 2014 installer had parameters that let SSRS create an instance and database. With a few tweaks we made with a custom console program that runs at the end of the installation, that worked well for us.

However, the new 2022 command line installation for SSRS 2022 does not appear to give you any options for creating an instance or database. At this point, short of some potential PowerShell options, the only way to get these is through the UI and we would rather not have our end customers have to deal with that, as it will likely result in support calls to us.

Am I missing anything obvious? I thought to possible create an .RSS file and have RS.exe do the work, but at this point I do not know if that is even possible. Nor do I have any documentation on how to write the VBA to do this.

Any thoughts are appreciated!